# Updating new notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am using following code to get notifications from a service

```
nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,test.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
        String body = "Hi this is test"+count;
        String title = "Ritu"+count;
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        n.number=++count;
        nm.notify(uniqueid, n);
```

Every time I am getting a new notification, the number on it gets incremented but when I open notification window I can see only one the latest notification and after clicking on it number of notification does not get decremented.
Where I am wrong please help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I have had this problem before. 

I think there may be a bug with android, but I cant remember. Try 
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueid, intent,Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

Comment: thanks for reply , but this is not working..:( , how u had sorted out your problem if possible try to recall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, in order to remove notification after click:

```
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

And instead of using:

```
n.number = ++count;
```

Use:

```
count++;
nm.notify(count, n);
```

This will allow you to have multiple notifications at the same time

Comment: if i am doing it like this i am getting multiple icons on my status bar, with "1" on first icon "2" on second icon and so on.

Comment: i want it like it will show only one icon on the status bar , with number on it getting updated with new notification, but i think its not possible because i read it here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4724a2069f70c43b/1fc7cc3e72b3dbe6?lnk=gst&q=number+on+notification#1fc7cc3e72b3dbe6 that notification manager supports only one icon per item , please suggest if you have some other way round.

Comment: What do you mean by "with number on it getting updated with new notification"? If you only want one notification at time, use:

Comment: By the way, this flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; work for deleting notification after click?

Comment: issue is that when i am opening notification window, its not showing all the notifications as shown in the icon for e.g. notification is showing that there are two notifications , but on opening the notification window i am only getting one notification which is the latest one.

Comment: Well, if you want the window to show all notifications, you need to set different id's in nm.notify(id, n); so you can use id++ before doing the notify.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i had tried that already but in that case i am getting multiple icons on the status bar.

Comment: I'm almost sure, that's the only way to do it mate

Comment: ok , thanks. You mean its not possible to have multiple notifications having only one icon on the status bar with total number of notifications showing over it as number.

Comment: Yeah, I'm almost sure it's not possible. But how about you accept my answer or vote up for the FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL I helped you with :P

Answer (score 0):

Follow this like if u can get help...

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/NotifyWithText.html

Comment: presently what is happening if a new notification is coming number over the icon on status bar getting updated , however when i am opening notification window i am getting only one notification which is the latest one.i.e its not showing all the notifications, i hope i am clear.

Comment: n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;